# Using guice in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, guice

I'm using Apache Camel 2.11.1 with camel-guice, but i can't figure out how to bootstrap a bean for autostartup.

With camel-context.xml I could write:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...
    <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="my-camel-context">
        <camel:packageScan>
            <camel:package>package.routes</camel:package>
        </camel:packageScan>        
    </camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="fooBean" class="package.beans.FooBean" />

    <bean id="barBean" class="package.beans.BarBean" >
        <constructor-arg ref="fooBean"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="my-camel-context"/>
    </bean>
...
</beans>
```

BarBean.class

```
public class BarBean implements SmartLifecycle, StartupListener {
...
}
```

And camel calls the hooks implemented in BarBean, but how do I solve this using guice?

edit: I'm using org.apache.camel.guice.Main to start my camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Camel` with `Guice` you are configuring your application via `CamelModule`, right?

Then `CamelModule` is using [wikipedia:JSR250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSR_250) or [JSR250](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250) which is officially specification for Common Annotations for the JavaTM Platform.

So, you can freely use them to manage object lifecycle.

To bootstrap your application your main look like this:

```
final Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new MyCamelModule());
    Main main = new Main() {
      @Override
      protected Injector getInjectorFromContext() throws Exception {
        return inj;
      }
    };
    main.enableHangupSupport();
    main.run(args);
```

Your `MyCamelModule` should contain `bind` your beans. It look like your beans are just implemented, so everything you have to do is put `@Inject` to your beans constructor.